# THREE.js Move Camera with Mouse With Limitations

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to move the camera around my JSON scene by only using mouse movements. However, I want the camera to move with only the movement of the mouse and in the direction of the mouse without having to click and drag.

I have developed a partially working version of this, but it isn't where I need it to be. I am also looking for the camera to stop moving at a certain point, in addition to the camera not changing the distance between itself and the animated JSON.

Here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - animation - keyframes - json</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>

            body {
                color: #fff;
                font-family:Monospace;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:center;
                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #info {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px; width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            a {
                color: #2983ff;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>

        <div id="info">
            <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> webgl - animation - keyframes - json
        </div>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


            var scene, camera, pointLight, stats;
            var model;
            var renderer, mixer, animationClip;

            var clock = new THREE.Clock();
            var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onresize, false );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 20, 20, 0x888888, 0x888888 );
            grid.position.set( 0, - 1.1, 0 );
            scene.add( grid );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 30;
            camera.position.y = 30;
            // camera.position.x = 0;
            // camera.position.set( - 5.00, 3.43, 11.31 );
            // camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( - 1.22, 2.18, 4.58 ) );

            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ) );

            pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
            pointLight.position.copy( camera.position );
            scene.add( pointLight );

            new THREE.ObjectLoader().load( 'FuckIt2.json', function ( model ) {

                scene.add( model );

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );
                mixer.clipAction( model.animations[ 0 ] ).play();
                //
                // model.position.y = 0;
                // model.position.x = 0;

                animate();

            } );

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfX ) / 5;
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfY ) / 5;

            }



            window.onresize = function () {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 1;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 1;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            };


            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                mixer.update( clock.getDelta() );

                stats.update();

                render();
            }

            function render() {

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.003;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.003;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know what I can do to change this! Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reinventing the wheel? I would just reuse the [TrackballControls.js](https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) code and modify it as you wish, if you don't want to have to press and drag the mouse to rotate the camera, then modify the event handling behavior and activate rotate mode by default, like I did in this - dirty - [codepen](https://codepen.io/leefsmp/pen/zEvaBK).

```
/**
 * @author Eberhard Graether / http://egraether.com/
 * @author Mark Lundin  / http://mark-lundin.com
 * @author Simone Manini / http://daron1337.github.io
 * @author Luca Antiga  / http://lantiga.github.io
 */

THREE.MyTrackballControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

  var _this = this;
  var STATE = { NONE: - 1, ROTATE: 0, ZOOM: 1, PAN: 2, TOUCH_ROTATE: 3, TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN: 4 };

  this.object = object;
  this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

  // API

  this.enabled = true;

  this.screen = { left: 0, top: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };

  this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  this.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  this.panSpeed = 0.3;

  this.noRotate = false;
  this.noZoom = false;
  this.noPan = false;

  this.staticMoving = false;
  this.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;

  this.minDistance = 0;
  this.maxDistance = Infinity;

  this.keys = [ 65 /*A*/, 83 /*S*/, 68 /*D*/ ];

  // internals

  this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

  var EPS = 0.000001;

  var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

  var _state = STATE.ROTATE,
    _prevState = STATE.NONE,


    _eye = new THREE.Vector3(),

    _movePrev = new THREE.Vector2(),
    _moveCurr = new THREE.Vector2(),

    _lastAxis = new THREE.Vector3(),
    _lastAngle = 0,

    _zoomStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
    _zoomEnd = new THREE.Vector2(),

    _touchZoomDistanceStart = 0,
    _touchZoomDistanceEnd = 0,

    _panStart = new THREE.Vector2(),
    _panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();

  // for reset

  this.target0 = this.target.clone();
  this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
  this.up0 = this.object.up.clone();

  // events

  var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
  var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
  var endEvent = { type: 'end' };


  // methods

  this.handleResize = function () {

    if ( this.domElement === document ) {

      this.screen.left = 0;
      this.screen.top = 0;
      this.screen.width = window.innerWidth;
      this.screen.height = window.innerHeight;

    } else {

      var box = this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      // adjustments come from similar code in the jquery offset() function
      var d = this.domElement.ownerDocument.documentElement;
      this.screen.left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - d.clientLeft;
      this.screen.top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - d.clientTop;
      this.screen.width = box.width;
      this.screen.height = box.height;

    }

  };

  this.handleEvent = function ( event ) {

    if ( typeof this[ event.type ] == 'function' ) {

      this[ event.type ]( event );

    }

  };

  var getMouseOnScreen = ( function () {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

    return function getMouseOnScreen( pageX, pageY ) {

      vector.set(
        ( pageX - _this.screen.left ) / _this.screen.width,
        ( pageY - _this.screen.top ) / _this.screen.height
      );

      return vector;

    };

  }() );

  var getMouseOnCircle = ( function () {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

    return function getMouseOnCircle( pageX, pageY ) {

      vector.set(
        ( ( pageX - _this.screen.width * 0.5 - _this.screen.left ) / ( _this.screen.width * 0.5 ) ),
        ( ( _this.screen.height + 2 * ( _this.screen.top - pageY ) ) / _this.screen.width ) // screen.width intentional
      );

      return vector;

    };

  }() );

  this.rotateCamera = ( function() {

    var axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
      quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(),
      eyeDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
      objectUpDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
      objectSidewaysDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
      moveDirection = new THREE.Vector3(),
      angle;

    return function rotateCamera() {

      moveDirection.set( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x, _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y, 0 );
      angle = moveDirection.length();

      if ( angle ) {

        _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );

        eyeDirection.copy( _eye ).normalize();
        objectUpDirection.copy( _this.object.up ).normalize();
        objectSidewaysDirection.crossVectors( objectUpDirection, eyeDirection ).normalize();

        objectUpDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.y - _movePrev.y );
        objectSidewaysDirection.setLength( _moveCurr.x - _movePrev.x );

        moveDirection.copy( objectUpDirection.add( objectSidewaysDirection ) );

        axis.crossVectors( moveDirection, _eye ).normalize();

        angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;
        quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle );

        _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
        _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

        _lastAxis.copy( axis );
        _lastAngle = angle;

      } else if ( ! _this.staticMoving && _lastAngle ) {

        _lastAngle *= Math.sqrt( 1.0 - _this.dynamicDampingFactor );
        _eye.copy( _this.object.position ).sub( _this.target );
        quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( _lastAxis, _lastAngle );
        _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
        _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

      }

      _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

    };

  }() );


  this.zoomCamera = function () {

    var factor;

    if ( _state === STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN ) {

      factor = _touchZoomDistanceStart / _touchZoomDistanceEnd;
      _touchZoomDistanceStart = _touchZoomDistanceEnd;
      _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

    } else {

      factor = 1.0 + ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * _this.zoomSpeed;

      if ( factor !== 1.0 && factor > 0.0 ) {

        _eye.multiplyScalar( factor );

      }

      if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

        _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

      } else {

        _zoomStart.y += ( _zoomEnd.y - _zoomStart.y ) * this.dynamicDampingFactor;

      }

    }

  };

  this.panCamera = ( function() {

    var mouseChange = new THREE.Vector2(),
      objectUp = new THREE.Vector3(),
      pan = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function panCamera() {

      mouseChange.copy( _panEnd ).sub( _panStart );

      if ( mouseChange.lengthSq() ) {

        mouseChange.multiplyScalar( _eye.length() * _this.panSpeed );

        pan.copy( _eye ).cross( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.x );
        pan.add( objectUp.copy( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.y ) );

        _this.object.position.add( pan );
        _this.target.add( pan );

        if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

          _panStart.copy( _panEnd );

        } else {

          _panStart.add( mouseChange.subVectors( _panEnd, _panStart ).multiplyScalar( _this.dynamicDampingFactor ) );

        }

      }

    };

  }() );

  this.checkDistances = function () {

    if ( ! _this.noZoom || ! _this.noPan ) {

      if ( _eye.lengthSq() > _this.maxDistance * _this.maxDistance ) {

        _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.maxDistance ) );
        _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

      }

      if ( _eye.lengthSq() < _this.minDistance * _this.minDistance ) {

        _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye.setLength( _this.minDistance ) );
        _zoomStart.copy( _zoomEnd );

      }

    }

  };

  this.update = function () {

    _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

    if ( ! _this.noRotate ) {

      _this.rotateCamera();

    }

    if ( ! _this.noZoom ) {

      _this.zoomCamera();

    }

    if ( ! _this.noPan ) {

      _this.panCamera();

    }

    _this.object.position.addVectors( _this.target, _eye );

    _this.checkDistances();

    _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

    if ( lastPosition.distanceToSquared( _this.object.position ) > EPS ) {

      _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

      lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );

    }

  };

  this.reset = function () {

    _state = STATE.NONE;
    _prevState = STATE.NONE;

    _this.target.copy( _this.target0 );
    _this.object.position.copy( _this.position0 );
    _this.object.up.copy( _this.up0 );

    _eye.subVectors( _this.object.position, _this.target );

    _this.object.lookAt( _this.target );

    _this.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

    lastPosition.copy( _this.object.position );

  };

  // listeners

  function keydown( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown );

    _prevState = _state;

    if ( _state !== STATE.NONE ) {

      return;

    } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ROTATE ] && ! _this.noRotate ) {

      _state = STATE.ROTATE;

    } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.ZOOM ] && ! _this.noZoom ) {

      _state = STATE.ZOOM;

    } else if ( event.keyCode === _this.keys[ STATE.PAN ] && ! _this.noPan ) {

      _state = STATE.PAN;

    }

  }

  function keyup( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    _state = _prevState;

    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );

  }

  function mousedown( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if ( _state === STATE.NONE ) {

      _state = event.button;

    }

    if ( _state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

      _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
      _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );

    } else if ( _state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

      _zoomStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
      _zoomEnd.copy( _zoomStart );

    } else if ( _state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

      _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );
      _panEnd.copy( _panStart );

    }

    //added by default
    //document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
    //document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

    _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

  }

  function mousemove( event ) {



    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if ( _state === STATE.ROTATE && ! _this.noRotate ) {

      _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
      _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

    } else if ( _state === STATE.ZOOM && ! _this.noZoom ) {

      _zoomEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

    } else if ( _state === STATE.PAN && ! _this.noPan ) {

      _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( event.pageX, event.pageY ) );

    }

  }

  function mouseup( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    //_state = STATE.NONE;

    //document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove );
    //document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup );
    _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

  }

  function mousewheel( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    switch ( event.deltaMode ) {

      case 2:
        // Zoom in pages
        _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.025;
        break;

      case 1:
        // Zoom in lines
        _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.01;
        break;

      default:
        // undefined, 0, assume pixels
        _zoomStart.y -= event.deltaY * 0.00025;
        break;

    }

    _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );
    _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

  }

  function touchstart( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    switch ( event.touches.length ) {

      case 1:
        _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
        _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
        _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
        break;

      default: // 2 or more
        _state = STATE.TOUCH_ZOOM_PAN;
        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
        _touchZoomDistanceEnd = _touchZoomDistanceStart = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

        var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
        var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
        _panStart.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
        _panEnd.copy( _panStart );
        break;

    }

    _this.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

  }

  function touchmove( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    switch ( event.touches.length ) {

      case 1:
        _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
        _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
        break;

      default: // 2 or more
        var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
        var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;
        _touchZoomDistanceEnd = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

        var x = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX + event.touches[ 1 ].pageX ) / 2;
        var y = ( event.touches[ 0 ].pageY + event.touches[ 1 ].pageY ) / 2;
        _panEnd.copy( getMouseOnScreen( x, y ) );
        break;

    }

  }

  function touchend( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    switch ( event.touches.length ) {

      case 0:
        _state = STATE.NONE;
        break;

      case 1:
        _state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;
        _moveCurr.copy( getMouseOnCircle( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY ) );
        _movePrev.copy( _moveCurr );
        break;

    }

    _this.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

  }

  function contextmenu( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();

  }

  this.dispose = function() {

    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
    this.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );

    window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
    window.removeEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

  };

  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', contextmenu, false );
  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', mousedown, false );
  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'wheel', mousewheel, false );

  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', touchstart, false );
  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', touchend, false );
  this.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', touchmove, false );

  window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keydown, false );
  window.addEventListener( 'keyup', keyup, false );

  this.handleResize();

  // force an update at start
  this.update();

  document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mousemove, false );
  document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', mouseup, false );
};

THREE.MyTrackballControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
THREE.MyTrackballControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.MyTrackballControls;


if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats;

var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

var cross;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 500;

  controls = new THREE.MyTrackballControls( camera );

  controls.rotateSpeed = 2.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;


  controls.noPan = false;

  controls.staticMoving = false;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

  controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

  controls.addEventListener(  'change', render );

  // world

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 10, 100, 16, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xdddddd, specular: 0x009900, shininess: 30, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );



  for ( var i = 0; i < 200; i ++ ) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.x = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 500;
    mesh.position.y = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 500;
    mesh.position.z = ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 500;
    mesh.updateMatrix();
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    scene.add( mesh );

  }


  // lights

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
  light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
  scene.add( light );

  light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
  scene.add( light );


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
  renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
  stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
  container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

  //

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
  //

  render();

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  controls.handleResize();

  render();

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  controls.update();


}

function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  stats.update();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and I keep getting error messages that say "Cannot read property 'update' at: THREE.MyTrackballControls.render
THREE.MyTrackballControls.dispatchEvent
THREE.MyTrackballControls.update"

Comment: A working live example is provided in the codepen link I created... more than that would be hard to do: https://codepen.io/leefsmp/pen/zEvaBK